# Self keep-alive MOSFET circuit

Tags: mosfet, dc, powermosfet, analog-switch

Is it possible to make a power-control circuit, that once activated by a switch will keep itself alive as long as there is an input voltage?

Like an N-channel MOSFET that gets a one-off input to gate, and then keeps drain-source connected by feeding it's own gate from it's source. It has to be such that the circuit is dead when voltage is applied, until the switch is pressed. Then it cannot power-off until the voltage is removed.

The circuit mentioned above doesn't work, but that's just the idea. What other components would I need to make this work? I've tried using a capacitor to keep the MOSFET on but that slowly depletes over time, seeing as it doesn't get charged back up once the switch is off.

See image for non-functional example of my thoughts.
Load is up to 20 W. Input 5 V.

[image: Non-functional example circuit]

Comment: What is the lower acceptable limit of input voltage for the circuit to work and latch?

Comment: What prevents use of a mechanical switch?

Comment: There will be a mechanical switch. The circuit is to make sure the system stays alive if the mechanical switch breaks. Lower voltage limit 5V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a latching switch, of which the classic example is the "zero volt release" control built with a relay.

The supply is connected to the C/O contact, the N/O "output" connects to the loads *and* back to the coil, and finally a momentary contact switch is placed between the supply and the coil.

When the relay is activated via the momentary switch, the N/O feeds power back to the coil, and keeps the relay energized even once the switch opens.  It stays in this state until power fails, at which point the contacts open, and the circuit resets.

It is used extensively in controls for machine tools, to make sure that equipment which was on, doesn't automatically restart after a power failure.

There are a variety of ways to build the same circuits with solid state components, and which is best depends on things such as current and voltage levels.

A range of examples can be found here http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/electronic-circuits/push-button-switch-turn-on/latching-toggle-power-switch with the third example perhaps being exactly what you need (just use a slightly higher rated dual MOSFET).

Many other references exist.  Look for "latching mosfet switch"

Comment: Thanks for your help. 

It seems these examples doesn't fully solve my problem, as the switch will be on constantly. The rest of the circuit is there to makes sure that the system stays alive even if the switch fails (i.e. the switch physically breaks somehow). A momentary switch is not possible to implement in my specific scenario.

Comment: All the examples which work with a momentary switch, will also keep the power on with a latching switch.  Does that not give you what you want?

Comment: Okay, great. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help.  If your questioned is resolved, please mark as answered.